# Prepared Statement issue in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a question re a project I'm doing in php/mysql.
I am designing a site where users can record their financial accounts (bank account/credit cards etc) and the transactions and their type that they undertake on a monthly basis on each one of them.
What I want is that the user selects a particular account and using GET I can take the account id, and use that to get all transactions associated with that account name.
Here is my code:

```
//connect to database
include ('connect-To-db.php');

//Ensure the id is appropriate
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
                        {
    // get 'id' using GET superglobal variable
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    // get the credits, debits & catagory from the transactions table for that account
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `Credit`,`Debit`,`Catagory` FROM `transactions` WHERE `Accname` IN
        (SELECT `Accname` FROM `Accounts` WHERE `accID`=?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($id,$Credit, $Debit, $Cat);

        //Loop through the results and display in a table format
        echo"<table>";
        echo "<th>Credits></th><th>Debits</th><th>Catagory</th>";

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>.$Credit.</td>";
            echo "<td>.$Debit.</td>";
            echo "<td>.$Cat.</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo "</table>";

        $stmt->close();
    }
    // show an error if there is a problem connecting to the table
    else {
        echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement".$mysqli->error;
    }
}
```

On trying to run this I get the error that I have a syntax error near " on line 2, however I do not have a " symbol on line 2.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To let you know, "asking for some assistance" is prohibited here. This site is about questions, not assistance.

Comment: No silly edit would help. It is not about wording but about the *matter*. Your "question" is still about "assistance", no matter how you worded it.

Comment: Personally its not a silly edit nor a request for assistance. I have clearly asked a question on this site from others who know more than me. I have asked the question what I have done wrong. It seems to me a rational and reasonable request.

Comment: Yes, it's no doubt a rational and reasonable request by itself. But just not suitable for this site, which is dedicated to practical and generalized programming questions, rather than finding typos in someone's code.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$mysqli->prepare("... WHERE `accID`=?"))
```

to:

```
$mysqli->prepare("... WHERE `accID`=?)"))
//                                   ^
```

You are missing the closing parenthesis for the subquery.

Comment: Cheers Jeffrey, however when I add the last parenthesis and I see I was one short I then get the error message that begins Syntax error unexpected: ) after ) expected: ext,if, integer, double, identifier, double, identifier and a lot of other text. How can this be as you are quite correct there is a missing parenthesis.